# Adding screen share option webrtc app. unable to get on other users

Tags: javascript, express, webrtc

i was adding screen share functionality to my app but its is not working .. its only show screen share on my side but not on other user.
here is code :

```
try {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getDisplayMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: true
    })
    .then((stream) => {
      const video1 = document.createElement("video");
      video1.controls = true;
      addVideoStream(video1, stream);

      socket.on("user-connected", (userId) => {
        const call = peer.call(userId, stream);
        stream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener("ended", () => {
          video1.remove();
        });
        call.on("close", () => {});
      });
      stream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener("ended", () => {
        video1.remove();
      });
    });
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Error: " + err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be related to signaling and that depends on each project.
You could start from a working example that streams webcam/microphone and then switch source to screen.

In this [HTML5 Live Streaming](https://demo.videowhisper.com/html5-videochat-php/) example, you can switch source between camera and desktop - transmission is the same. So you could achive somethign similar by starting from an example for camera streaming and testing that first.